# php-handling dynamic created radio button

Tags: php, html

I am creating a dynamic quiz page with two options for each question and a radio button to compare its value to the value in the database in order to know if the answer is correct

the questions and choices are stored in a database and retrieved in the code with every question in its own table

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" class="RegularFont" action="quiz.php">
        <?php
        require_once 'database.php';

        $res = mysql_query("select * from quiz");
        while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {\\create a table for every entry
            echo <<<_END
        <div style="padding-bottom: 30px">
        <table border="">
        <th colspan="2">question 1</th>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2">  $row1[0] </td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
        <td>$row1[1]<input type="radio" name='true1[$row1[1]]' value='1'></td>
        <td>$row1[2]<input type="radio" name='true1[$row1[1]]' value='2'></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
_END;
        }

        ?>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

so the value of each radio button can be 1 or 2 , and I want to compare it with value from the database where I have the correct answer as a number 1 or 2

I tried to use

```
foreach ($_POST['true1'] as $value)
```

but cant get it right , I want this to work dynamically for any number of inputs

Comment: I think your `foreach` should work. Please provide more details about how it's failing.

Comment: when I am using `foreach` , the `$value` is the value of each radio so I am good for here , but how I am gonna compare this value with the value corresponding to it (found in the database) and if its equal , I want to increment a variable x for example.

Comment: My answer below doesn't address that?

Comment: Well , I can compare `$key` with `$value` assuming that the associative array contains the value of the correct answer '1' or '2' , but if you can imagine column of correct_answer it would be '1'/'2'/'1'/'1' so that would ruin that radio buttons would not be unique for every question, I hope you understand me

Comment: You don't compare `$key` with `$value`. You compare it with the column in the database, since that's where it came from when you created `name=true1[$row1[1]]'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should use:

```
foreach ($_POST['true1'] as $key => $value)
```

You need `$key` so you know which row of the database the radio selection refers to.